# How can I know how many free RAM and CPU slots are on my hpe proliant dl380 gen10 host

Tags: hardware, hp-proliant, hpe, specifications

I need help with knowing how much free RAM and CPU slots I have on my Proliant DL380 Gen10 server. Is there any software I can deploy to the server that enables me to know what specs do I have on the server? Also I think it is worth mentioning I have ESXi installed on it. Another thing I need to know is what type of RAM and CPU is used on that host, in case I want to add more in the future.

Thanks

Comment: iLO............

Comment: at firsty the ilo, second go to the server and take a look into. third, ask the support of your vendor

Comment: Unfortunately iLO isn't configured on the server, and I can't go look into it since it is stacked under other severs. Any other suggestions please?

Comment: @AhmedHassan Remote management is the whole point of buying real servers. If iLO has never been configured, plug the port into management, and get the password from the front pull-out tab.

Answer (score 0):

Use your ESXi console find the spec. ESXi list a lot of hardware information.

From there use HP Product Bulletin to see what your server support. (https://h41370.www4.hpe.com/quickspecs/overview.html)